Can you baptize your baby with Gatorade in an emergency?
An AI priest named "Father Justin" came under fire for providing incorrect information.
From ‘I just have to take my lumps’:

I asked if I could baptize my baby with Gatorade in an emergency, and ‘Father Justin’ said yes — and of course, that’s not true. I can’t baptize my baby with Gatorade.

But is it true that in the Catholic Church, Gatorade is impermissible for baptism? What types of water are acceptable?

Related: for the Islamic perspective, Hadith says, the well of budah was pure for ablution (islamic baptism before prayers), the well was full of dead animals and filthy rags of menstrual clothes. https://sunnah.com/search?q=well+buda%27ah+water+pure

Yes, Gatorade is invalid matter for baptism. Natural water is the only valid matter.

The remote matter of baptism, then, is water, and this taken in its usual meaning. Theologians tell us consequently that what men would ordinarily declare water is valid baptismal material, whether it be water of the sea, or fountain, or well, or marsh; whether it be clear or turbid; fresh or salty; hot or cold; colored or uncolored. Water derived from melted ice, snow, or hail is also valid. If, however, ice, snow, or hail be not melted, they do not come under the designation water. Dew, sulfur or mineral water, and that which is derived from steam are also valid matter for this sacrament. As to a mixture of water and some other material, it is held as proper matter, provided the water certainly predominates and the mixture would still be called water. Invalid matter is every liquid that is not usually designated true water. Such are oil, saliva, wine, tears, milk, sweat, beer, soup, the juice of fruits, and any mixture containing water which men would no longer call water. When it is doubtful whether a liquid could really be called water, it is not permissible to use it for baptism except in case of absolute necessity when no certainly valid matter can be obtained. -- Baptism

Gatorade may be mostly water but it would not ordinarily be called water, so it does not satisfy the requirements.

Of course, this begs the question, what about "vitamin water"? What about "flavored water"?

@Matthew The answer seems to make it pretty clear those aren't valid. Vitamin water and flavored water are basically the same as gatorade regardless.

@LukeHill, I'm not sure I see how. They are examples of "water" with additions. Are you saying that only "natural" water is permitted? If so, does that mean that water to which minerals have been deliberately added is proscribed?

@Matthew there's a pretty clear difference between adding minerals (something that I'm fairly certain all modern water treatment plants do) and flavored vitamin water. This seems like a fairly silly point to try and argue.

@Matthew Unless there's a different variety of vitamin water, it seems like that is generally similar to Gatorade in that it is flavored and colored. Color doesn't ipso facto make it invalid, but if it wouldn't be commonly considered water, it would be invalid. "When it is doubtful whether a liquid could really be called water, it is not permissible to use"
